# Archive of the Work of J Sutherland Frame

Tags: ho.history-overview

Does anyone know of the existence of an archive of the work of J Sutherland Frame?

The Briscoe Center for American History maintains about 100 archives of American mathematics and I have found the folks there to be quite helpful.

Cheers, Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no".   Frame did interesting work, though usually 
outside the conceptual mainstream of representation theory.    Some of his
calculations of character tables (such as that of the most exceptional
Weyl group) have permanent value, I think.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Michigan State University Archives](http://archives.msu.edu/findaid/ua17-142.html)

DKS